# Make macro produce compile time error for non-existing function

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I've got several functions in a namespace. The parameters are different, for every invocation they store an object containing a string member to a vector.
There are no overloaded functions in the namespace.

I'd like to create a macro that produces a lambda expression for matching objects created via a call of a certain function. In addition to that the macro should also result in a compile time error iff a function with the name provided as parameter does not exists in the namespace. Influencing results in case of an successful compilation? (If possible at all the compilation results with and without this check would be the same without relying on code that may or may not be optimized out based on optimization level.) Is this possible? If it is possible: How can I implement this?

Example of what I'm trying to achieve; the macro I'm asking about is `CALL_INFO_PREDICATE`; the `static_assert_function_exists` part is a placeholder for any code that would achieve the desired result:

```
struct CallInfo
{
    const std::string m_function;
    CallInfo(const std::string& function)
        : m_function(function)
    {
    }
}

std::vector<CallInfo*> g_calledFunctions;

namespace mymath
{

    // all functions with same return type, but differnent parameter lists

    double sin(double radian)
    {
        g_calledFunctions.push_back(new CallInfo("sin"));
        ...
    }

    double atan2(double y, double x)
    {
        g_calledFunctions.push_back(new CallInfo("atan2"));
        ...
    }
    
}

#define CALL_INFO_PREDICATE(functionName) [] (CallInfo* info) -> bool\
{\
    static_assert_function_exists(mymath::functionName);/* << how to make this work? */\
    return info->m_function == #functionName;\
}

int main ()
{
    mymath::sin(1);
    mymath::atan2(3, 7);

    auto pos = std::find_if(g_calledFunctions.begin(), g_calledFunctions.end(), CALL_INFO_PREDICATE(sin)); // compiles; function sin exists in mymath

    auto pos2 = std::find_if(g_calledFunctions.begin(), g_calledFunctions.end(), CALL_INFO_PREDICATE(cos)); // produces compile time error, since there is no function named cos in mymath

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just use it, assuming no overloads:

```
#define CALL_INFO_PREDICATE(functionName) [] (CallInfo* info) -> bool \
{ \
    static_cast<void>(&mymath::functionName); \
    return info->m_function == #functionName; \
}
```

cast to `void` to avoid warning for unused expression.

Comment: Do you happen to know, Is C++ guaranteed to optimize this out or if it just very likely according to the standard? (Btw: sorry that I won't be providing feedback for some time. Cannot test this out immediately, but it looks promising.)

Comment: Taking address is no-op.

Comment: @fabian &math::functionName is essentially a constant value. It can't be made into code even if the compiler tries.

Answer (score 2):

Why not store the function pointers in the `CallInfo` and eliminate the need for macros?

```
struct CallInfo
{
    const std::string m_function;
    void* m_function_ptr;
    CallInfo(const std::string& function, void* function_ptr)
        : m_function(function),
          m_function_ptr(function_ptr)
    {
    }
}

std::vector<CallInfo*> g_calledFunctions;

namespace mymath
{

    // all functions with same return type, but differnent parameter lists

    double sin(double radian)
    {
        g_calledFunctions.push_back(new CallInfo("sin", sin));
        ...
    }

    double atan2(double y, double x)
    {
        g_calledFunctions.push_back(new CallInfo("atan2", atan2));
        ...
    }
    
}

int main ()
{
    mymath::sin(1);
    mymath::atan2(3, 7);

    auto pos = std::find_if(g_calledFunctions.begin(), g_calledFunctions.end(), [](CallInfo* info) { return info->m_function_ptr == &mymath::sin; });

    auto pos2 = std::find_if(g_calledFunctions.begin(), g_calledFunctions.end(), [](CallInfo* info) { return info->m_function_ptr == &mymath::cos; });

    // ...
}
```

Now the compiler can check for you automatically whether the function exists.